# Efficient average of pandas dataframe with selected rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe consisting of a tuple index and several columns with float dtype. I would like to average the values of different, not necessarily contiguous, rows in an efficient manner.

My current approach uses itertuples to iterate through each row, select the rows that are to be averaged, compute the average and store it in a new dataframe.

Ideally, I would like to avoid using itertuples and find a vectorized solution for better performance. Does that solution exist?

Here is the code of the itertuples approach:

```
def parameters_list_between_range(parameters: Tuple[int, ...], param_range: Tuple[int, ...],
                                  min_values: Tuple[int, ...]=None, max_values: Tuple[int, ...]=None) -> List[Tuple[int, ...]]:
    """
    Builds a list of parameters that have as center the parameters tuple and reside between +/- (inclusive) the param_range.
    I.e. if parameters = (2, 3, 1) and param_range=(0, 2, 1) it returns a list with all parameters between (2, 1, 0) and (2, 5, 2).
    If min_values or max_values is provided then it restricts the results to parameters that do not surpass those limits.
    :param parameters: A tuple with the parameters around which to build the list.
    :param param_range: A tuple indicating for each entry the range.
    :param min_values: A tuple that enforces a minimum value for each parameter.
    :param max_values: A tuple that enforces a maximum value for each parameter.
    :return: A list of parameters tuples.
    """
    if len(parameters) == len(param_range):
        min_parameter_range = tuple(parameters[i] - param_range[i] for i in range(len(parameters)))
        max_parameter_range = tuple(parameters[i] + param_range[i] + 1 for i in range(len(parameters)))
        if min_values is not None:
            min_parameter_range = tuple(max(x, y) for x, y in zip(min_parameter_range, min_values))
        if max_values is not None:
            max_parameter_range = tuple(min(x, y) for x, y in zip(max_parameter_range, max_values))
        min_max_parameter_range = tuple(zip(min_parameter_range, max_parameter_range))
        parameters_combinatorial = product(*tuple(map(list, list(starmap(range, min_max_parameter_range)))))
    else:
        raise ValueError("Length of parameters and param_range is not equal.")
    return list(parameters_combinatorial)


def average_neighbors(input_df: pd.DataFrame, param_range: Tuple[int, ...], min_values: Tuple[int, ...]=None, max_values: Tuple[int, ...]=None)\
        -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Averages the input_df with the neighbor values defined by the param_range.
    :param input_df: A DataFrame with indexed by tuples with the measurements.
    :param param_range: A tuple indicating for each parameter the distance of the maximum neighbor to average with.
    :param min_values: A tuple that enforces a minimum value for each parameter.
    :param max_values: A tuple that enforces a maximum value for each parameter.
    :return: A Dataframe of the same shape as the input_df but where each value has been averaged with its neighbors.
    """
    averaged_df = input_df.copy()  # type: pd.DataFrame
    # TODO: itertuples is not efficient. Does a vectorized approach exist?
    for row in input_df.itertuples():
        sub_df = input_df.loc[parameters_list_between_range(row[0], param_range, min_values, max_values)]
        averaged_row = sub_df.mean(axis=0)
        averaged_df.at[row[0],:] = averaged_row
    return averaged_df
```

EDIT:
Adding an example input_df and the resulting averaged_df:
The invocation is:

```
average_neighbors(input_df, (2, 1), (5, 5), (9, 9))
```

input_df

```
               1         2         3         4         5
0
(5, 5) -0.034785  0.105553  0.175304 -0.100131 -0.087695
(5, 6) -0.019643  0.007028 -0.117302 -0.188429  0.140423
(5, 7)  1.090219  0.149492  0.134205  0.298541 -0.766889
(5, 8)  0.233639  0.011140 -0.070625  0.296987 -0.555725
(5, 9) -0.160929 -0.054387  0.149795 -0.236799 -0.236427
(6, 5) -0.053750 -0.105638  0.306676  0.075424 -0.253134
(6, 6)  0.488996 -0.104845  0.037985  0.097563  0.816975
(6, 7) -0.273730 -0.006430  0.048764  0.337964 -0.558355
(6, 8) -0.279250 -0.039354  0.139512  0.312060 -0.440458
(6, 9) -0.215230 -0.077674 -0.059508  0.731031  0.146549
(7, 5) -0.447961  0.114293  0.032839  0.042610 -0.158302
(7, 6) -0.151704 -0.006943  0.053286 -0.276120  0.084298
(7, 7)  0.690647 -0.053874  0.171092  0.461872  0.164381
(7, 8)  0.431084  0.166979  0.224027  0.226597  0.116096
(7, 9) -0.548030  0.021681  0.504869  0.347923 -0.307202
(8, 5)  0.903684  0.059785  0.143359  0.423591  0.046842
(8, 6)  0.424536 -0.025986  0.089045 -0.086571  0.004112
(8, 7) -0.036251  0.172838  0.391125 -0.253686  0.049140
(8, 8) -0.251853  0.035594  0.088101  0.154551 -0.071685
(8, 9) -0.314121 -0.002571 -0.035833  0.134743 -0.115290
(9, 5)  0.083115 -0.063250  0.192984 -0.030540  0.265402
(9, 6) -0.300660  0.136081  0.203255 -0.115099  0.014861
(9, 7) -0.276533  0.031048  0.041306  0.193987 -0.504231
(9, 8)  0.336343 -0.053169  0.037187  0.081937 -0.042678
(9, 9)  0.041883 -0.178786  0.094013 -0.110578 -0.242337
```

averaged_df

```
               1         2         3         4         5
0                                                       
(5, 5) -0.036474  0.001575  0.081465 -0.058180  0.090428
(5, 6)  0.143143  0.010960  0.093650  0.083255 -0.068700
(5, 7)  0.245584  0.013688  0.068994  0.174115 -0.111028
(5, 8)  0.107602  0.013064  0.138015  0.308464 -0.270892
(5, 9) -0.089786  0.004731  0.148012  0.279633 -0.212861
(6, 5)  0.138672  0.005406  0.090149 -0.001508  0.074190
(6, 6)  0.215021  0.025439  0.122198  0.069386 -0.043184
(6, 7)  0.195557  0.025470  0.099101  0.115111 -0.084807
(6, 8)  0.030516  0.026953  0.140460  0.234315 -0.214655
(6, 9) -0.138086  0.007676  0.117542  0.245887 -0.183018
(7, 5)  0.089183  0.011608  0.111743 -0.015770  0.087378
(7, 6)  0.139079  0.027277  0.126928  0.058732 -0.049478
(7, 7)  0.140389  0.027973  0.098064  0.102810 -0.103316
(7, 8)  0.031192  0.008168  0.123869  0.198475 -0.224341
(7, 9) -0.072647 -0.017055  0.107154  0.193845 -0.174916
(8, 5)  0.118282  0.000437  0.132429  0.016357  0.102632
(8, 6)  0.087532  0.012257  0.142643  0.072583 -0.002334
(8, 7)  0.066802  0.020995  0.127057  0.094588 -0.030629
(8, 8) -0.057920  0.001357  0.137055  0.218200 -0.150506
(8, 9) -0.099897 -0.015913  0.124046  0.234783 -0.119626
(9, 5)  0.085168  0.035664  0.119128 -0.007021  0.042869
(9, 6)  0.098764  0.040444  0.146477  0.040005 -0.003722
(9, 7)  0.096179  0.044730  0.144269  0.043052 -0.020634
(9, 8)  0.008130  0.015527  0.168432  0.137483 -0.105978
(9, 9) -0.050783 -0.001712  0.152061  0.139195 -0.110516
```

Comment: Please show a small example input df and the expected output. It reads like this could just be done using `groupby`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Added a small sample of the input_df and the output produced. I did attempt using groupby but didn't get it to work, any suggestion is welcomed.